# Plotting text in Cartopy just inside my figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot some big cities of Spain and tag them with their names, according to Natural Earth data. If I only plot the points, using ax.scatter, I get my figure correctly, without points outside it. But when doing ax.text in the same way, I get all the names of cities of the world outside the picture...

The code is here:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Downloaded from https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html. Those are the borders
fname = 'C:/Users/lordf/Downloads/gadm36_ESP_shp/gadm36_ESP_2.shp'
adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())

cname = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='10m', category='cultural', name='populated_places')
reader = shpreader.Reader(cname) #data of cities

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-10, 1, 35, 45], ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.title('Spain')
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')

ax.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray', alpha=0.5) #borders

points = list(reader.geometries())
cities = list(reader.records())

ax.scatter([point.x for point in points],
           [point.y for point in points],
           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
           s=[10*np.exp(1/(city.attributes['SCALERANK']+1)) for city in cities], c='r')
          #trying to match the size of the point to the population

#This gives me error, dont know why:
# ax.text([point.x for point in points], [point.y for point in points], 
#         [city.attributes['NAME'] for city in cities], 
#         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

#This is what plots the text outside the figure:
for i in range(len(points)):
    ax.text(points[i].x, points[i].y, cities[i].attributes['NAME'], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent([-10, 1, 35, 45], ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

[This is part of the image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQh8J.png)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You plot all the world's city names.

Comment: Yeah, but I did the same with the points and it only shows the ones inside the figure

Comment: The option `s=...city...` in `ax.scatter()` suppresses points outside Spain. Maybe those points are skipped because of invalid values of `s`.

Comment: If s=10, the result is the same... That cannot be the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must select only `points` and `cities` of `Kingdom of Spain` before plotting. Here is the relevant code:

```
spain_points = []
spain_cities = []
for city,xy in zip(cities, points):
    if city.attributes["SOV0NAME"]=="Kingdom of Spain":
        print(city.attributes["NAME"], xy)
        spain_points.append(xy)
        spain_cities.append(city)
        pass
    pass
```

Then proceed with `spain_points` and `spain_cities` in places of `points` and `cities` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can create a dataframe, containing information like city name, lat and lon. Then you can do something like:

```
# add cities
for i in range(UK_cities.shape[0]):
    ax.text(UK_cities['lon'][i],UK_cities['lat'][i],UK_cities['City_name'][i],fontsize=15,weight='bold')
```

Here I just copied my codes used for plotting UK cities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know how to extract Spain cities from the data set, but I'll try. But what confuses me is that when plotting the points, it shows the ones inside the figure (good), but when plotting the text, it shows every city... It's strange.